# for given data i need to find the count of "a" in the column Key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
     Key
----------
0     a
1     a
2     b
3     b
4     a
5     c
```

so far i tried this:

```
df.groupby(["key1"],).count()
```

However it is also showing the counts of b and c, i want only for a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create mask and count by `sum`:

```
df["Key"].eq('a').sum()
```